# Django API allow POST via the URL

Tags: django, tastypie

I have started using [TasyPie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/) for an API and have build the following resource below. My issue is that client using the API does not makes POSTs in json i.e.

It's asks for POSTs like this....

```
http://somedomain/a/path?id={{ticket.external_id}}&status={{ticket.status}}
```

**How to I allow POST via the URL?**  As at the moment TasyPie only works with json POST in the body.

```
class SMSResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        queryset = Batch.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'sms'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client consuming your API does not support POST HTTP method then you need to design a secure way to simulate POST using the GET method. Changing data using GET is not SAFE, so if you have no other option you need to think through the security.

I have not used Tastypie framework, but this could be helpful. 
[Using PUT/DELETE/PATCH In Unsupported Places](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#using-put-delete-patch-in-unsupported-places)

EDIT:
Also check the "Content-Type" in your header. For JSON POST it is application/json, and for a regular form POST it should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: It does support POST but not in json just a form POST. but taskypie does not seem to allow this format.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood that part. Check "Content-Type" in the http header then, if you are sending JSON data it is set as application/json. If you remove this and set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded then it should accept regular form submissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send POST via url. It's http method in header, not url.

Comment: so I guess its a form post which again it won't allow? how to I make a form post as well as json POST?